# Windows 8.1 - BITS service stuck on 'stopping' despite reboots

Tags: windows-8.1

I followed some advice I found online that told me to go into 'view local services' and disable then stop BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) to fix an issue where 100% hard disk usage was causing slowdown.

However, the BITS process seems to have stuck on 'stopping' for weeks and through several reboots. Here is the result of 'sc query bits' command in command prompt:

```
    C:\windows\system32>sc query bits

    SERVICE_NAME: bits
    TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
    STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                            (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the advice exactly?  Of course the service specifically indicates it cannot be stopped and is unlikely to be the source of your hdd usage.

Comment: The advice I followed was on this page. http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2045646/windows-100-disk-usage.html

Comment: The status of the service changed to 'stopping' following me taking the actions mentioned on that page. Thanks for your time.